# How to create bitbucket PR from command line

Tags: bitbucket

Is there a way to create pull requests for bitbucket from the command line.
Ideally some solution that would avoid a REST API or that would open up a browser

Comment: You can use REST API in Power Shell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2